# How to separate first result of query from the rest?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I want to separate first array of PDO-result from other arrays. Here is my try:

```
$iterator = 1;
while($results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and $iterator == 1){
    /* I need just first row here */
    print_r($results);
    $iterator++;
}

while($results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    /* I need other rows here */
    print_r($results);
}
```

But **only** first `while()` executes in my code *(the above code always just print first result of the query)*. Well, how can I fix it?

**Note:** I don't want to use `fetchAll();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$results = $stm1->fetch();
print_r($results);

while($results = $stm1->fetch()){
    print_r($results);
}
```

You don't actually need a loop to get the first element, and then you can resume iteration with what used to be your second loop.

The problem with

> ```
> while($results = $stm1->fetch() and $iterator == 1){
> ```

is that if there is one or more results in the result set, you will *always* call `$stm1->fetch()` twice: once the first time you enter the loop, and then a second time on the second iteration before you actually check that `($iterator == 1)` is no longer true.

If there are only two results in your result set, then that will manifest in the second loop never being entered (because fetch will not have any results left).

Comment: there is no need for while() control structure in the first case – simple $firstRow = $stm1->fetch() is sufficient. making a loop and breaking after the first iteration is overkill

Comment: @DenisMysenko yes; I just adjusted accordingly. Minor brainfart when answering the question too literally.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a while loop, since you only want to fetch the 1 row you don't need a while loop, just do:

```
$firstRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And after that you can put your while loop as you already did.

Comment: Well how to fetch the rest of rows after that?

Comment: one 'issue' with that - second loop will miss the first row (since it has already been fetched). just don't forget to include $firstRow shall you need a full set somewhere later in the code

Comment: @stack nm the first part which I had in my answer, I did a mistake there. The only thing, which happens is after the first iteration it will first fetch the second row and then check if `$iterator == 1`, which then evaluates to false and so you don't enter the loop again, but you fetched the second row

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

will gives only the first row of your query execution . even if you use while it will result only the first row.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

will gives the all records of your query execution.